# How to create a com object in another domain?

Tags: powershell, com, credentials, remote-server

I'm trying to use PowerShell to quickly find the Scheduled Tasks in the root folder of a remote server. I find all sorts of scripts that others have written, but they're either looking at the localhost or on a server in the same domain. I support servers in dozens of domains, so I need some way to pass along credentials.

Here's the meat of my script:

```
$server = "<computername>"
$schedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service") 
$Schedule.connect($server)
$folder = $schedule.GetFolder("") 
$tasks = $folder.GetTasks("")
foreach($task in $tasks) {
if (($task = $Folder.GetTasks(0))) {
    $Tasks| ForEach-Object {[array]$results += $_}
    $Tasks | Foreach-Object {
        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            'Name' = $_.name
            <etc.>
            <etc.>
        }
    }
}
```

That code works fine either on my localhost or a server in the same domain as my workstation. In other scripts, I use Get-Credential to create $creds and (in various ways) pass that to the appropriate cmdlet. But with this one, I'm not sure. 'New-Object' doesn't accept a -Credential parameter. I've tried wrapping various parts inside an Invoke-Command scriptblock, since that accepts -Credential, but it fails in various ways. I'm not sure what needs to be wrapped in Invoke-Command--just the new-object? The foreach loop? The entire thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can upgrade to powershell 4, it has scheduled task cmdlets. I know it doesn't answer the question, but it is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing the `Connect` call, you can pass the server, domain, username, and password:

```
$Schedule.Connect($serverName, $user, $domain, $password);
```

This should allow you to use that object on the new domain.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I think that will do it, Eris. Working with your answer, I find that the method only works on Vista and up. I still support quite a few Windows 2003 servers, but fewer and fewer every month, so that's a diminishing problem. I also see that this method won't work with servers in a DMZ. It just throws exception errors, which I'll have to handle. But this gets me a long way there.